# Runtime error : Heap Buffer overflow in Leet code

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, duplicates, function-definition

I am having a problem with this code on Leetcode. In there , I am solving a problem to remove duplicates in an array but I am getting heap buffer overflow error -

Here's the code -

```
int removeDuplicates(int* nums, int numsSize) {

    int i,j,temp,k=0,num = *(nums+numsSize-1);

    for(i = 0;i<numsSize;i++){
        
        if(*(nums+i) == *(nums+i+1)){


            if(num != *(nums+i)){
                k++;
            }
        
            for(j = i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
                temp = *(nums+j);
                *(nums+j) = *(nums+j+1);
                *(nums+j+1) = temp; 

            }
            num = *(nums+i);
            i--;

        }
    }
    return k;
    
}
```

I want to know what causing this error and how to solve it?

Comment: When `i == (numSize - 1)` (which it will be in the last iteration of the loop), then `*(nums+i+1)` will be out of bounds.

Comment: Also note that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The array-indexing syntax is usually easier to read and understand. And less to write.

Comment: `for(j = i+1;j<numsSize;j++){` should probably be `j < numsSize - 1` because of de-referencing `*(nums+j+1)`

Comment: @Harshit Kumar Your code is unclear. Is the array sorted? What does this code snippet if(num != *(nums+i)){
                k++;
            } mean?  And this loop              for(j = i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
                temp = *(nums+j);
                *(nums+j) = *(nums+j+1);
                *(nums+j+1) = temp; 

            } makes your code inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, for the sake of readability get rid of all access in the form of `*(nums+i)` and replace it with `nums[i]`.

At the last iteration of the loop, `if(*(nums+i) == *(nums+i+1)){` will overflow, because `nums+i+1` is then equivalent to `nums + numsSize-1 + 1` which is one item out of bounds.

You can solve this by for example doing `for(i = 1; i<numsSize; i++){` and then `if(nums[i-1] == nums[i])`.

Same issue with `*(nums+j+1);`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the task is either to remove duplicates from a sorted array or to remove adjacent duplicated elements in any array.

First of all the function should be declared like

```
size_t removeDuplicates(int* nums, size_t numsSize);
```

that is the type of its second parameter and the return type should be the unsigned integer type `size_t` instead of the signed integer type `int`. Leet code does not learn how to write professional code.

Your code has bugs, a logical error and is inefficient.

This line

```
int i,j,temp,k=0,num = *(nums+numsSize-1);
```

is already wrong. The user may pass any value for the parameter `numsSize` as for instance `0`. In this case the expression  *`(nums+numsSize-1)` invokes undefined behavior.

Or for example if a passed array has no duplicates then your function returns `k` equal to `0` due to skipping this if statement

```
    if(*(nums+i) == *(nums+i+1)){


        if(num != *(nums+i)){
            k++;
        }
        //...
```

(where in the nested if statement the variable `k` is incremented) instead of returning the actual number of unique elements.

Or consider for example an array like `{ 1, 1, 1 }` where all elements are equal each other. In this case `num` will be always equal to  `*(nums+i)`. So the returned value of `k` again will be equal to `0` while you have to return `1`.

The function is inefficient due to this for loop

```
        for(j = i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
            temp = *(nums+j);
            *(nums+j) = *(nums+j+1);
            *(nums+j+1) = temp; 

        }
```

where for some iterations of the outer for loop all elements of a sub-array of the original array are moved left.

And the function contains bugs due to accessing memory outside the array when `i` in the outer for loop or `j` in the inner for loop are equal to `numsSize - 1` because expressions `i+1` and `j+1` are equal to `numsSize` while the valid range of indices for the array is `[0, numsSize)`.

I would define the function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t removeDuplicates( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t unique = 0;

    if (n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[unique] != a[i])
            {
                if (i != ++unique)
                {
                    a[unique] = a[i];
                }
            }
        }

        ++unique;
    }

    return unique;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

    size_t unique = removeDuplicates( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < unique; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

If you want to reformat a sorted array such a way that all values stored in the array were kept and duplicated elements were moved to the tail of the array then there are two possibilities: whether the moved elements will be stored in the sorted order or in the reversed sorted order.

Here are another two demomnstration programs.

In the first program the function moves duplicated elements to the tail of an array in the reversed sorted order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t removeDuplicates( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t unique = 0;

    if (n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < n; )
        {
            if (a[unique] != a[i])
            {
                if (i != ++unique)
                {
                    a[unique] = a[i];
                }
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                memmove( a + i, a + i + 1, ( n - i - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
                a[--n] = tmp;
            }
        }

        ++unique;
    }

    return unique;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t unique = removeDuplicates( a, n );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < unique; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

In the second program the function moves duplicated elements to the tail of an array in the initial sorted order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t removeDuplicates( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t unique = 0;

    if (n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1, m = n; i < m; )
        {
            if (a[unique] != a[i])
            {
                if (i != ++unique)
                {
                    a[unique] = a[i];
                }
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                memmove( a + i, a + i + 1, ( n - i - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
                a[n - 1] = tmp;
                --m;
            }
        }

        ++unique;
    }

    return unique;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t unique = removeDuplicates( a, n );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < unique; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

As you can see in the both cases all stored values in arrays are preserved without changes.